# Expo React Native - Deploying multiple apps with same codebase

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm created an ejected ExpoKit app for a customer

I’m looking to duplicate the same app for another customer. What are the best ways to do this?

Expo's Release Channels looks like it would work for the JS codebase. I am struggling to find a way to duplicate the Native (iOS and Android) projects.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit

It is a menu app that has the restaurant's branding. A user can order from the app.

Each app will be named after the business e.g. Ben's Diner, so I will need to have different apps.

I want to keep as much of the codebase the same.

Comment: Why can't you give them the same app you gave the first one?

Comment: If you actually need to have different native codebases (do you really?), then there's no other way than actually copy-pasting your entire folder and replacing bundleIdentifiers and package names manually. But I think you should better describe your use case (why do you actually need 2 apps) we could help you better.

Comment: You can try this `exp publish` After doing this, share your uri with the other person.